# how to convert bean:write to c:out

Tags: jsp, javabeans, ctags

I have a bean:write to convert to c:out

```
<bean:write name="${param.formName}" property="${param.path}.fileName" />
```

How to do it, like this?

```
<c:out value="${ ${ param.forName }.${ param.path }.fileName }">
```